# How to remove edge forms completely from a pie chart?

Tags: charts

Consider a pie chart as follows

```
PieChart[Normalize@RandomReal[1, 10], SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
 ChartStyle -> RandomColor[10], ColorFunction -> (EdgeForm[None] &)]
```

The corresponding chart is

[image]

If one looks closely at the chart, one can find the white edges (one such sample is outlined in the chart). I want a smooth pie chart without any such edge.

How can I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this problem persist if you `Rationalize` the inputs?  This might help avoid rounding error.  (I'd try it out myself, but my institution is currently migrating their Mathematica license server...)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
ini = PieChart[Normalize@RandomReal[1, 10], SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1},
         ChartStyle -> RandomColor[10], ColorFunction -> (EdgeForm[None] &)];
```

The annulus pieces probably partition the complete one as good as exactly, but maybe the rendering rounds off badly. From the output of `head @@ ini`, you can see that the style of each piece is a `Directive` with the form `Directive[col, EdgeForm[None]]`.

Replacing those with appropiate `EdgeForm`s can counteract the bad rounding:

```
ini /. Directive[col_, EdgeForm[___]] :> Directive[col, EdgeForm[{col, Thickness[1/1000]}]]
```